# Django rest framework : custom object permissions doesn't work

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My problem is very simple : I'm trying to create some custom permissions for my django rest API. This is my code (*permission.py*) :

```
class UserPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user
```

I just want that the users can only get, delete and update their own account.
The problem is that I think my code is not read by Django. I have try to always return false (without any condition) and it does nothing. I have also try to print some debug message at the beginning of the file and it's does nothing.

(My file *permissions.py* is at the root of my application)$

This is my user view (*UserView.py*) :

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by("-date_joined")
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    swagger_tag = ["User"]

class LoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    """
    API endpoint allowing the user to login and receive a token
    """

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny,
    ]

    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=AuthTokenSerializer)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
        login(request, user)
        return super(LoginView, self).post(request, format=None)
```

Comment: Can you share view as well?

Comment: @UtkucanBıyıklı i edit my message with the view!

Comment: Where is the UserPermission you added into view?

Comment: UserPermission is added into a file call "permission.py", not in my view. Is it the problem ? @UtkucanBıyıklı

Comment: @crevdav: yes, since you do not "link" it to any view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@UtkucanBıyıklı](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289060/django-rest-framework-custom-object-permissions-doesnt-work#comment131155467_74289060) says in their comment, you should specify the permission in the `ViewSet`:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, UserPermissions]
    swagger_tag = ['User']
```